# unable to resolve null pointer excet

Tags: android

```
     02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:810)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:265)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at com.example.printing.adapter$1.onClick(adapter.java:335)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18428)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
02-16 10:10:48.126: E/AndroidRuntime(9838):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: How we can find the error without code?

Comment: Please... specify what you want to ask.. tell us what is scenario, what are you doing in code, and what is not happening

Comment: What has `WindowManager$BadTokenException` to do with `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 1):

As in log:

> WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is
>   not for an application

means currently passing `getApplicationContext()` to `Dialog` constroctor for creating Dialog object.

Use live component context which is currently visible to user for creating `Dialog` object.

If creating Dialog in Activity then use `CurrentActivityName.this`  instead  `getApplicationContext()`.

or if using inside `onClick` method of any View then use `onClick` method parameter for getting context like if `onClick(View view)` then use `view.getContext()` to get context